# StratifiedShuffleSplit reporting multiple args for n_iter

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm trying to use scikit-learn's StratifiedShuffleSplit to make a single split of my dataset that preserves class sample ratios.

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_files
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedShuffleSplit
dataset = load_files('reviews/aggregated/')
split = StratifiedShuffleSplit(dataset.target, n_iter=1, test_size=0.2)
train_idx, test_idx = next(iter(split))
train_X, train_y = dataset.data[train_idx], dataset.target[train_idx]
test_X, test_y = dataset.data[test_idx], dataset.target[test_idx]
```

This gives me the below error:

```
TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for keyword argument 'n_iter'
```

But I'm clearly only passing a single value for it. Is StratifiedShuffleSplit somehow incompatible with datasets? The docs don't seem to have an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out [the documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.StratifiedShuffleSplit.html) was outdated. Looking at the docstrings, I found that the correct way to do this is:

```
sss = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_iter=1, test_size=0.2)
train_idx, test_idx = next(sss.split(dataset.data, dataset.target))
```